# Unable to mount "Volume1" folder on NAS

Tags: networking, permissions, mount, samba, fstab

To copy a patch file to the NAS I have on my network, I need to excess the Volume1 folder.

Usually I mount my NAS with Samba, but when I do that I have no access to the Volume1, and the invisible folders in there.

I have tried:

```
sudo mount 192.168.0.200
```

```
sudo mount 192.168.0.200:/volume1
```

But both commands give the error:

> can't find in /etc/fstab.

I assume i have to configure `/etc/fstab` correctly, but i don't know how really, but for one, I do not see fstab folder in `/etc`.

Also I am not sure how to deal with the username and password issue.

A pointer in the right direction would be much appreciated.

---

In reply to the answer by Jos: I did the following.

```
sudo mkdir /mnt/vol
sudo mount -t cifs //192.168.0.200/volume1 /mnt/vol
```

The error message was:

```
mount: /mnt/vol: bad option; for several filesystems (e.g. nfs, cifs) you might need a /sbin/mount.<type> helper program.
```

The following error message was:

```
mount error(2): No such file or directory
Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs)
```

---

The output of `smbclient -L 192.168.0.200` was:

```
    Sharename       Type      Comment
    ---------       ----      -------
    Home            Disk      Home directory
    Public          Disk      System default share
    Web             Disk      Web default shared folder
    Download        Disk      Download default share.
    Plex            Disk      Default location for Plex library.
    Movies          Disk      
    Photo           Disk      
    Ebooks          Disk      
    Documents       Disk           
    MyArchive1      Disk      MyArchive: Series
    IPC$            IPC       IPC Service ()
Reconnecting with SMB1 for workgroup listing.

    Server               Comment
    ---------            -------

    Workgroup            Master
    ---------            -------
    WORKGROUP
```

---

This is what needs to be done according to this thread, but from windows remote instead of Linux.

https://forum.kodi.tv/showthread.php?tid=330347

What to do when copying?

1. In ADM Services > Enable "Terminal" port 22
2. Download WinSCP from "https://winscp.net/eng/download.php"
3. Install WinSCP as a Commander type
4. Run WinSCP
5. Create connection -> protocol "SCP" + host "your ip NAS" + port 22 + username "root" and password.
6. After success connect > on the right panel goto / and copy volume1 (you must find volume1 from download dropbox in left side panel) from the left side to the right side .

---

Just got a phone call from a friend that was coming over. I asked if i could borrow his laptop (windows) to do this and got it fixed easily. 
I love Ubuntu, but sometimes the use of Windows can be very helpful, unfortunately.

Still I would love to be able to do this through Ubuntu too.

Comment: Are you sure `volume1` is being shared? What is the output of `smbclient -L 192.168.0.200` ?

Comment: to be honoust i don't know much about volume1 (not even sure about it's spelling) except that it is supposed to be there, as being drive1 (or the root there of) and that i need access to solve an audio issue within kodi, as certain codex are no longer supported by asustor (nas brand) which leaves me without sounds for most of my files.

Comment: OK so `Volume1` is probably just a storage container name rather than an actual Samba share: you will need to mount one of the shared folders e.g. `sudo mount -t cifs //192.168.0.200/Documents /mnt/vol`

Comment: unfortunately no, i actually need the documents to be placed at a specific location. as you said all the shared folders are indeed folders in the root. i need to place it in the root of volume1 so the system can access it

Comment: Well in that case I don't think you can do so via CIFS - it's possible the volume is accessible via another protocol though (e.g. an NFS export, or SSHFS/SCP)

Comment: indeed, according to the windoes methos, scp protocol needs to be used. 
unfortunately i have no idea about the differences between these protocols.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need the `fstab` to mount a file system once, you can use the mount command for that. Only if you want the file system mounted at startup would you enter a line in the `fstab`. However, on the mount command, you need to specify more parameters. First you need to create a mount point, let's say:

```
sudo mkdir /mnt/nas
```

Now tell mount what to do. Specify the file system type (CIFS for Samba) with the `-t` flag:

```
sudo mount -t cifs //192.168.0.200/volume1 /mnt/nas
```

Notice position and number of the slashes. If this command is successful, the contents of your NAS are accessible under `/mnt/nas`.

Depending on the settings of the NAS you may need to specify other parameters, like username/password, but try this first. When that works, edit the `fstab`.

Comment: oke, thank you very much. at work at the moment but i will try and respond this evening. much appreciated. As indeed it is just a one time event i will refrain from editing fstab.

Comment: I tried it, but i recieved an error msg, i added it at the bottom of my orrginal question. for clearity

Comment: No problem. Do `sudo apt install cifs-utils`.

Comment: that solved that problem indeed, but now it returns another error. please find it again under the original question

Comment: after googling i tried the following: sudo apt-get install keyutils, as i found references that it might work in a similar circumstance. unfortunately it didnt

Comment: The error message could mean a couple of things, unfortunately. You may need to do `sudo chmod 777 /mnt/vol`, or add `-o sec=ntlmv2` to the command, or specify a username/password on the command. Or all three. Samba errors are notoriously vague.

Comment: seems like sudo chmod 777  and -o sec=ntlmv2 did something.. i am rebooting the router see if that helps any

Comment: it gave an error that host was down, i rebooted the router and checked the nas. After this i received again another mount error (2). it does ask for the hosts password, which i entered. I assume volume1 is the root of the first drive in the nas, which i normally don't have access to when i normally excess the nas via samba (nautilus)

i am not sure how to specify a username/password on the command. but i will look into that.

Comment: I found this question here that deals with a similar problem. 
but the naming of volume1 is different, namely volume_1. how can i verify the correct naming? https://askubuntu.com/questions/923714/mount-a-nas-drive-in-ubuntu-server-permission-problems?rq=1

Comment: That is the share name, as displayed in Windows as well, if you use Windows networking to access the NAS from there. I have a NAS myself where the two disks are named `volume_1` and `volume_2`.

Comment: oke. that means ik could be an error in the file name. using volume1 instead of volume_1, at the moment i am nog connected to my network. but i will check that.

Comment: neither volume1 not volume_1 seems to work.

Comment: I'm trying to solve the same problem and getting the same errors but in your case, note that Linux is case-sensitive so perhaps it is ***V***olume_1 as it is on mine rather than ***v***olume_1.